# Align two images (cover image) using css no matter screensize?

Tags: html, css

I have a left image:
https://i.ibb.co/ZGjdwJ5/c-left.jpg

...and a right image:
https://i.ibb.co/9WP7Nnr/c-right.jpg

How can I align these two images, so they always look like this:
[image]

I want the two white arrows to be visible and aligned no matter the screen size.

I've tried this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#left {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/ZGjdwJ5/c-left.jpg") no-repeat right center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#right {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/9WP7Nnr/c-right.jpg") no-repeat left center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div id="left" class="full"></div>
  <div id="right" class="full"></div>
</div>
```

But I can't make it work.

I need to align them, so they look like a single coverimage, but still be two images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `fixed` from your background rule:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#left {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/ZGjdwJ5/c-left.jpg") no-repeat right center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#right {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/9WP7Nnr/c-right.jpg") no-repeat left center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div id="left" class="full"></div>
  <div id="right" class="full"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg ... that simple. I've spent hours! :) Thanks a million!